# Using boost::asio io_service for thread pool with periodic tasks?

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

I found this recipe for creating thread pools with boost: http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes. I got it running and it works. However, I have tasks that happen, let's say, all 50 milli seconds.

Now, one solution would be occupying a thread adding such a task every 50 milli second to the thread pool, i.e. to the io_service. I can really not think of how to do this without an extra thread. Can someone please try?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use `deadline timer` (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

However, it depends on what other tasks you have for your `io_service`. For example, if you schedule relatively fast functions to `io_service`, then you should definitely use `deadline_timer`. But if you schedule very long tasks and require this periodic timeout handler to execute more or less in equal intervals, you have two possibilities:

1. provide enough threads (multiple threads can invoke `io_service::run()` method at the same time, exactly as in example from your link)
2. handle your timer in dedicated thread